# Openssl for m68k

Tags: linux, openssl, coldfire

I need to cross compile **openssl for m68k** board, **Linux OS** kernel **2.6.10**..Any pointers on which openssl version to be used . Currently i am trying to use **0.9.8**. I want to cross compile it for using it with wpa_supplicant (**version 0.7.3**).

**Note: wpa_supplicant needs libssl.a and libcrypto.a so i statically link it while compiling wpa_supplicant**

Basically i tried compiling it and was successful indeed but while executing the wpa_supplicant i get **illegal instruction** :(

Right now am trying to work on the compiler settings but in case if i am missing anything important please let me know

Answer (score 0):

I was facing some issue in compilation (it was because of the following reason) i missed these settings andd after including these settings i was able to compile and run them along with wpa_supplicant without any trouble). Need to test them completely but atleast it is now compiling without any trouble.

build = i686-pc-linux-gnu
build_cpu = i686
build_os = linux-gnu
build_vendor = pc
host = m68k-unknown-none
host_alias = m68k
host_cpu = m68k